# Allow only specifi character else null should transfer in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Allow characters in 2nd columns are 0 to 9 and A to Z and Symbol like "+" and "-", if allow character found in 2nd column then complete record should be Transfer else null should be Transfer in 2nd column 
*Input*

```
 - 1|89+ 
 - 2|-AB 
 - 3|XY* 
 - 4|PR%
```

*Output*

```
 - 1|89+ 
 - 2|-AB 
 - 3|<null> 
 - 4|<null>

grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\|]+$' file > file1
```

but above code is discard complete record if matching not found, I Need all records but if matching found then it should Transfer else null Transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to replace everything after a pipe, that begins with zero or more characters in the class of digits, letters, plus or minus followed by one character not in that class up to the end of the string with a pipe only.

```
sed 's/\|[0-9a-zA-Z+-]*[^0-9a-zA-Z+-].*$/|/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and character classes where supported:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}$2~/[^[:alnum:]+-]/{$2=""}1' file
1|89+
2|-AB
3|
4|
```

Where not supported (such as mawk) use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}$2~/[^A-Za-z0-9+-]/{$2=""}1' file
```